# Facet with function solr

Tags: solr, solr4, facet

**Doc #1**

```
{
  year1:1990;
  year2:1996
}
```

**Doc #2**

```
{
  year1:2011;
  year2:2014
}
```

**Doc #3**

```
{
  year1:2000;
  year2:2006
}
```

I want `facets` of `year2-year1`. So here result will be like

**year2-year1 : no of docs**

**6 : 2 (Doc #1,#3)**

**3 : 1 (Doc #2)**

Currently we cannot run functions with facets I believe

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1581

Is there any way to achieve this with just a `SOLR` query?

Comment: Is it an option to calculate this at indexing time?

Comment: That will be the last option for me. As i already have huge indexed data in core.